# Data passing probelm between files in next js

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

So i have three files here :-

**project.js**

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link'
import { DATA } from '../../components/Data'


const WEB_RELATED = []
const PC_EXES = []

for(let i=0;i<DATA.length; i++){
    if(DATA[i]['loc'] == 'WEB'){
        WEB_RELATED.push(DATA[i])
    }
    else if(DATA[i]['loc'] == 'EXE'){
        PC_EXES.push(DATA[i])
    }
}

const WEB = WEB_RELATED.map(item =>
    <div className="PROJECTS_Projects">
        <div className="PROJECTS_Projects_Image">
            <Image
                className='PROJECTS_Projects_image'
                src={item['img']}
                layout='fill'
            // objectFit='contain'
            />
        </div>
        {/* if someone clicks on this link i want them to go to [project].js and send This item to [projcet].js */}
        <Link href={'/projects/' + WEB_RELATED.indexOf(item)}>
            <a>{item['title']}</a>
        </Link>
        <p>{item['desc']}</p>
    </div>
);
const PC = PC_EXES.map(item =>
    <div className="PROJECTS_Projects">
        <div className="PROJECTS_Projects_Image">
            <Image
                className='PROJECTS_Projects_image'
                src={item['img']}
                layout='fill'
            // objectFit='contain'
            />
        </div>
        {/* if someone clicks on this link i want them to go to [project].js and send This item to [projcet].js */}
        <Link href={'/projects/' + PC_EXES.indexOf(item)}>
            <a>{item['title']}</a>
        </Link>
        <p>{item['desc']}</p>
    </div>
);


export default function index() {
    return (
        <div className="PROJECTS_Container">
            <div className="PROJECTS_Sub_Container">

                <div className="PROJECTS_New">

                    <h1>Web-Related</h1>

                    <div className="PROJECTS_Present">

                        {WEB}

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div className="PROJECTS_New">

                    <h1>Pc apllications</h1>

                    <div className="PROJECTS_Present">

                        {PC}

                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Project Display page [project.js]**

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { DATA } from '../../components/Data';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

export default function title() {

    const router = useRouter();
    const { project } = router.query
    const [state, setState] = useState()

    // when user comes here i want the item sent to be read and injected into the html
    useEffect(() => {
        // project && console.log('value', project, 'length : ', project.length);
        // setState(project)
        console.log(DATA[project]['loc'])
    }, [router])

    return (
        <div className='DISPLAY_Container'>
            <div className="DISPLAY_Sub_Container">
                <div className="DISPLAY_Image">
                    <Image
                        src={'/img/Projects/Cluq.PNG'}
                        layout='fill'
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="DISPLAY_Info">
                    <h3>{state}</h3>
                    <a href="">SUS</a>
                    <p>lorem300</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**DATA.JS file where i've kept all of the objects i want to be shown**

```
export const DATA = [
    {
        'loc':'WEB',
        'title':"Bukkit List",
        'img':'/img/Projects/Bukkit-List.PNG',
        'desc':"Bukkit-List is a easy to use and free task managing webapp, with password protection now!",
        'fullDesc':""
    },
    {
        'loc':'WEB',
        'title':"SilenxIka-Github",
        'img':'/img/Projects/SilenxIkaGithub.PNG',
        'desc':"First github website for Project SilenxIka, which is completly made from vanilla HTML/CSS/JS",
        'fullDesc':""
    }
]
```

when someone presses a link in the first file (check there are coments above the link) the item in the link shall be passed to the second file and i can use the item in [project].js file to inject it into the html

Comment: One issue is that you split the `DATA` array into `WEB_RELATED` and `PC_EXES` arrays, and then look for the index of an item in each array. This makes it possible that `PC_EXES.indexOf(item)` and `WEB_RELATED.indexOf(item)` provide the same index value. Instead you should get the index from the DATA array:  `DATA.indexOf(item)`. Now you can append that index to your url and use it in other pages as: `DATA[indexFromUrl]`

Answer (score 0):

You can append query parameters to your url and use the `useRouter` hook from `"next/router"` for getting the content of those query parameters in your other file.

Let's imagine your `item` object has an `id` and we want to append that `id` as a query parameter to your route:

In **project.js**:

```
export const arrayOfItems = [
   {id: 'A', title: 'A title'},
   {id: 'B', title: 'B title'},
   {id: 'C', title: 'C title'},
   {id: 'D', title: 'D title'},
];

// Add query param "item_id" plus the id of your item to your url (note the '?')
{arrayOfItems.map((item)=> 
   <Link href={'/projects?item_id= + item.id }>
      <a>{item.title}</a>
   </Link>
)
```

In your product display page:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { arrayOfItems } from "./project.js"; // path to where array is exported from

const ProductPage = () => {
   const router = useRouter();

   useEffect(() => {
     // here you have access to the query parameters 
     console.log(router.query?.item_id); 
     // get item_id from route
     const routeItemId = router.query?.item_id;
     // search through array and find item with matching id
     const matchingItem = arrayOfItems.find((item)=> item.id === routeItemId && item);
     console.log(matchedItem);
   }, [router]);

return(<></>)
}
```

Comment: How can i use the item? like the item is like a map right? do i do item['title'] to get the title? or item.get('title')? how do i use that item? Like in the return() html section

Comment: I've updated the example. The idea is that you have 1 single array that you use across your files and components. We need to know which item of the array is used on your product page. If we add the `id` to the link, then we can read it from the url in the product component. I've updated the example to highlight this.